# API keys exposed as 'strings' in my public git respositories

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have code like this in my git respository, but it is not a good idea beacuse my API keys are exposed in strings and everyone can see it.

So my question is how can I handle this problem? Should I save this API keys to *.txt file and import this strings?. And add this txt file to .gitignore file?

Can you suggest what would be the proper way of tackling this problem?

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const FETCH_LOCATION = 'FETCH_LOCATION';
export const FETCH_WEATHER = 'FETCH_WEATHER';
export const HISTORY_SELECTED = 'HISTORY_SELECTED';
export const SHOW_INFO = 'SHOW_INFO';
const API_KEY_GOOGLE = 'string';
const API_KEY_WUNDERGROUND = 'string';

export function fetchLocation(city) {
  const urlGoogle = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=${city}&key=${API_KEY_GOOGLE}`;
  const request = axios.get(urlGoogle);
```

Comment: A config file that is on the  `.gitignore` list is the way to go. Instead of a `txt` file you would use a `json` or `js` file, because then you won't need to create an own parser for that. Another way would be to use enviroment variables or application arguments.

Comment: Save your keys in a separate file, it can be a js file, not need to do it as txt, and then import your keys, add your file to .gitignore

Comment: FYI: AWS recently launched Secrets Manager service https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-secrets-manager-store-distribute-and-rotate-credentials-securely/

Comment: How are you deploying?  Are you using continuous integration?  Removing the keys from your code is the obvious first step, but getting them back into you code, in a maintainable manner, at the correct time, is dependent on your deploy step.

Comment: What you want to do is a good idea and first step, but always remember that you're writing front-end javascript code. Your keys WILL be visible in the source code for everyone to see.

For google maps API keys you can add CORS settings and allow certain keys to only be accessed from certain origins, which basically protects them from unauthorized use. I don't know about the other services, though.

Comment: I sure hope you haven't already committed or pushed that...

Comment: @gerrit that's assuming the "unauthorized use" isn't sophisticated enough to spoof an origin header, which is trivial to do from any server, as opposed to a script running on the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common practice is to use `.env` files, and ignore `.env` in .gitignore. You will load these files into `process.env`. You can use a package called `dotenv`.

For example, if I need a google API, I create a file call `.env`, then store it like

```
GOOGLEAPIKEY=asdfewvger343sdfasdf
```

If you are loading it with `webpack`, then add it as a plugin

```
import DotEnvPlugin from 'webpack-dotenv-plugin';

plugins: [
    new DotenvPlugin({
      sample: './.env.default',
      path: './.env.dev',
    }),
... 
]
```

Or you can just use `dotenv`

```
require('dotenv').config()
```

This will load `.env` file from your root without config.

Read more on this
https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv

In your app, you will use googleapi, like `process.env.GOOGLEAPIKEY`

```
 const data = await axios
      .post(`localhost:3000/api/helloworld/${process.env.GOOGLEAPIKEY}`)
      .send(data.fetchData);
```